# SQL Server Query output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of people records like this:

```
Tableid PeopleID DeptID StartMonth StartYear
--------------------------------------------
  1       101        1       3        2014
  2       101        2       2        2015
  3       102        2       5        2015
  4       102        5       4        2013
  5       103        6       8        2015
  6       103        7       9        2015
```

I want only the lastest workhistory for each `peopleid` with the corresponding `tableid`, meaning I want to have the following output:

```
tableid  peopleid  
2        101
3        102
6        103
```

Here I require only `tableid` and `peopleid` in output.

Comment: Can you change your start month + date to be a one date field? It's a lot easier to use that in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by peopleid
                                order by startyear desc, startmonth desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY`. Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE People 
(
    Tableid INT,
    PeopleID INT,
    DeptID INT,
    StartMonth INT,
    StartYear INT
)

INSERT INTO People
    SELECT  1,       101,        1,      3,         2014
    UNION ALL SELECT  2,       101,        2,      2,         2015
    UNION ALL SELECT  3,       102,        2,       5,        2015
    UNION ALL SELECT  4,       102,        5,       4,       2013
    UNION ALL SELECT  5,       103,        6,       8,        2015
    UNION ALL SELECT  6,       103,        7,       9,        2015

;WITH CTE as 
( 
    SELECT Tableid,PeopleID,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PeopleID ORDER BY StartYear DESC,StartMonth DESC) r
    FROM People
)
SELECT Tableid, PeopleID FROM CTE
WHERE r = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not use `row_number()` and will therefore work on versions of SQL Server before 2005:

```
SELECT Tableid, PeopleID 
FROM People t_outer 
WHERE Tableid = (SELECT TOP 1 Tableid FROM MyTable t_inner WHERE t_inner.PeopleID = t_outer.PeopleID ORDER BY StartYear DESC, StartMonth DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t2.PeopleID = t.PeopleID 
                   AND t2.StartYear * 100 + t2.StartMonth > t.StartYear * 100 + t.StartMonth
                  )
```

Comment: You might want to document why this answer is correct.